# When the dependent variable is Median Time of a specific event, have we to use Quantile Regression or OLS Regression works well?

Tags: regression, median, quantile-regression

I am asked to make a regression model and the dependent variable is Median Time of a specific event.

I think I can consider the Median Time of that event as a random variable and therefore the average of sample size can be an unbiased estimate of real mean of the population (Median Time of that specific event).  This means that I can use OLS regression instead of Quantile Regression. Am I right?

Comment: 'Median' suggests there were originally multiple times. Is that true? If so, do you have the original data? By "time of a specific event", are you referring to the event's duration? If so, there are methods ([tag:survival] analyses) that are appropriate for this kind of data. Did you consider those & decide against for some reason? Also, is there any censoring in the original data?

Comment: If the data **are** median times, you have a choice either way: you can apply plain linear regression (which need not imply OLS) or quantile regression (and indeed other methods might make as much as more sense including various generalised linear models). If the data are times, and you want to estimate medians, then quantile regression sounds more obvious. That said, it is not clear why being a random variable should imply unbiasedness. No such statement is possible without a probability model and precision on what is being estimated.

Comment: The Median Time id Median of a Wait Time for an event to occur.  We don't have data on those who are still waiting.  Our data only includes for those have finished waiting period and therefore have a definite value for the Wait Time measure.  Otherwise, I was thinking on Survival Analysis too.